# Trying to format datepicker date value utilizing JQuery?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

This is essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', $("#datepicker").val());
```

Any ideas/advice?

Comment: var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();

Comment: I figured it out ... var form_date = new Date($('#datepicker').val());
            var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', form_date);

Comment: I tested your suggestion as well ... it returned the date value in $('#datepicker').val() but not formatted as 'yy-mm-dd' format ...

Answer (score 0):

```
var form_date = new Date($('#datepicker').val());
var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', form_date);
```